# Deploy Microsoft Azure API jar on karaf

Tags: maven, azure, apache-karaf

i am new to Maven and OSGI, can anyone please help me knowing how to deploy Microsoft Azure API jar on karaf OSGI container?
Following is pom content of my Maven project.

            com.microsoft.windowsazure
            microsoft-windowsazure-api
            0.4.3

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

i have embedded dependencies like following

```
                                         <Embed-Dependency>
                        microsoft-windowsazure-api,
                        commons-lang3,
                        commons-logging,
                        jackson-core-asl,
                        jackson-jaxrs,
                        jackson-mapper-asl,
                        jackson-xc,
                        javax.inject,
                        jaxb-impl,
                        jersey-client,
                        jersey-core,
                        jersey-json,
                        jettison,
                        mail
                    </Embed-Dependency>
```

When i do this it keeps showing missing dependencies for different packages. i have imported all packages `(*)` in pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download bnd.jar (bundle tool)

keep azur and bnd both jar in a directory

go to that directory and run following command

```
java -jar bnd.jar wrap microsoft-windowsazure-api 0.4.3.jar
```

tada... your bundle is ready, just deploy it and continue your work :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jcloud feature for Karaf it also contains some bundles for azure. I'm sure this will give you a list of bundles working.