# Include OSGI jar for JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, osgi, pom.xml

I have a OSGI bundle which uses external jar for logging.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>Tracking-Service</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tracking_Service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

During build time I have a JUnit test which calls the logging jar. But the jars are not deployed into OSGI framework and I get NPE.

In the end I need to have logging jar which is also in

```
<scope>provided</scope>
<scope>test</scope>
```

Is there a way to include the logging jar also as mock test?

Comment: Are you talking of a custom jar for logging you built or of one of the big logging systems like log4j?

Answer (score 1):

there are two possible ways of getting that jar with your OSGI bundle

- get a OSGI version of that jar(bundle) and deploy it(if using Karaf, try searching for the feature if it is available) [Spring Repo for OSGI bundles](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/)

if and only if you do not find the first one

- you can embed it into your bundle as shown below

in your maven build plugin add following

```
<Embed-Dependency>jar_name</Embed-Dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

if you are using eclipse, you can use following plugin in your pom file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Embed-Dependency>jar_name</Embed-Dependency>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you give me some more information how I can do this with Apache Felix?

Comment: Felix supports embedding from version 1.2.0 onwards, read here https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

Comment: also if you want to make your jar as a bundle and deploy in Felix, you can refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17803834/2381006

Comment: By the way this will embed the bundle only during the build time or it will copy the logging jar into the parent jar?